# Add Title to message box with several lines

Tags: vba, msgbox

I've got an about message box which when the user presses a button, a message box opens and prints information about the software, on several lines. In an attempt to make it look neater, I wish to remove the 'Microsoft Excel' title for the message box. What I did was I put two commas after the message, which I normally do, but with one line of text but I keep getting expression errors with an equals sign or an invalid syntax error. Could someone help?

Here's my current code :)

```
    Private Sub about_button_Click()
    MsgBox ("Name: gemUI" & vbCrLf & "Version: 1.0" & vbCrLf & "Build: 0001" & _
    vbCrLf & "(C) 2018 Josh Face", , "About gemUI")
    End Sub
```

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated :)
Have a good evening :)

Josh

Comment: Take out the outside parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one too many parentheses. Ether take out the outside parenthesis surrounding the arguments or use the `Call` keyword.

```
Private Sub about_button_Click()
    MsgBox "Name: gemUI" & vbCrLf & "Version: 1.0" & vbCrLf & "Build: 0001" & _
        vbCrLf & "(C) 2018 Josh Face", , "About gemUI"
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub about_button_Click()
    Call MsgBox( "Name: gemUI" & vbCrLf & "Version: 1.0" & vbCrLf & "Build: 0001" & _
        vbCrLf & "(C) 2018 Josh Face", , "About gemUI")
End Sub
```

In `VBA` you call a subroutine with either

```
MySub arg1, arg2, arg3
```

or

```
Call MySub(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

When you write

```
MySub (arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

it tries to combine the multiple arguments into one thing and it fails.

Comment: @JoshF just to clarify the last bit: `DoSomething (something)` is taking `something`, evaluating it as a value expression, and passed `ByVal` to `DoSomething` even if `DoSomething`'s signature states it's taking it `ByRef`. Extraneous parentheses are not only compile-time problems, they can easily alter how your code is running, and introduce very hard-to-diagose bugs.

Answer (score 0):

just to add a (maybe) less clumsy way:

```
MsgBox Join(Array("Name: gemUI", "Version: 1.0", "Build: 0001", "(C) 2018 Josh Face"), vbCrLf), , "About gemUI"
```